# RStudio in docker image does not deal with some librairies

Tags: docker, rstudio

I have a problem to use the docker rstudio-image `rocker/rstudio` proposed
on https://www.rocker-project.org/ (docker containers for R). Since I am a beginner with both docker and RStudio, I suspect the problem comes from me and does not deserve a bug report:

- I open a proper terminal with 'Docker Quickstart Terminal'
- where I run the image with `docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e DISABLE_AUTH=true -v <...>:/home/rstudio/<...> --name rstudio rocker/rstudio`
- in my browser I then get a nice RStudio instance at the address http://192.168.99.100:8787
- but in this instance I can't install several packages such as `xml2`. I get the message:

  ```
  Using PKG_CFLAGS= 
  Using PKG_LIBS=-lxml2
  ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
  Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
   * deb: libxml2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
   * rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
   * csw: libxml2_dev (Solaris)
  If libxml-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
  PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libxml-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
  is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
  R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’
  * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xml2’
  Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
  ```

I don't know whether `xml2` is on the image but the file `libxml-2.0.pc` does exist on my laptop in the directory `/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig` and `pkg-config` is in `/opt/local/bin`. So I tried linking these pkg paths when running
the image (to see what happen when I play with the image environment
in RStudio), adding options `-v
/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:/home/rstudio/lib/pkgconfig -v
/opt/local/bin:/home/rstudio/bin` to the run command. But it doesn't work: for some reason
I don't see the content of `lib/pkgconfig` in RStudio...

Also the RStudio instance does not accept root/sudo commands so I can't
use tools such as `apt-get` in the RStudio terminal

so, what's the trick ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries on your laptop (the host for docker) are not available for docker containers. You should create a custom image with required libraries, create a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM rocker/rstudio

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libxml2-dev # add any additional libraries you need

CMD ["/init"]
```

Above I added the `libxml2-dev` but you can add as many libraries as you need.

Then build your image using this command (you need to execute below command in directory there you created `Dockerfile`):

`docker build -t my_rstudio:0.1 .`

Then you can start your container:

`docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e DISABLE_AUTH=true --name rstudio my_rstudio:0.1`

(you can add any additional arguments like `-v` to above).